# Moving localization folders in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I've recently upgraded from Xcode 3 to Xcode 4.2, and migrated an existing iOS apps to use this new version.  This app is localized, and I now want to add another language.

Under Xcode 4, when I add the new localization, it creates the country specific folder in the project root.  For example:

```
/fr.lproj
```

All of my prior language folders are in a Resources sub-folder, however.  Such as:

```
/Resources/de.lproj
/Resources/en.lproj
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to get Xcode 4 to move the new language folder to `Resources`.  There is no GUI option I can find.  If I move the physical folder using Finder, Xcode just changes the reference to red, but gives me no option to fix it.

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE:**

Here are a few screenshots demonstrating the problem (using Chinese this time):

The file listing:

[image: The actual file in Xcode]

The identity section for that file.  Note that I can't change it:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the solution.  It's not pretty, but it works.

Here's what I did:

1. View the contents of the `.xcodeproj` folder in Finder
2. Edit the `project.pbxproj` file
3. Search for `.lproj` within the file
4. Change the `path =` section to include the `Resources` part of the path.
5. Save, then restart Xcode

This smoothed everything over, and allowed the Localization to reside in the Resources subdirectory.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way how to solve it w/o editing .pbxproj file (Xcode 4.6.3):

1. select localization parent file (Localizable.strings)
2. Utility pane > Identity and Type > under Location (Relative to Group) choose path icon and set required new location for localization files
3. Finder > move all your en.lproj, fr.lproj, etc subfolders to that chosen folder

*UPD*: doesn't work in Xcode 8 :(

Comment: This helped me fix a similar problem where I wanted to move my Main.storyboard to a new location but it wasn't going where I wanted. The location in Utility pane was what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This way works on Xcode 5.1 also (Greek example):

1. Create `Resources/el.lproj` folder within `Localizable.strings` file in Finder
2. Open your project file in Xcode and right-click on `Resource` folder
3. Click on "Add File to..." context menu item
4. Select Localizable.strings file from `Resources/el.lproj` folder -> OK.
   Greek `Localizable.strings` automatically will be added to `Localizable.strings` files.

You can use the same way to add localization for xib files.

Answer (score 0):

The file structure on disk is mostly irrelevant in Xcode. Just move the directory in Finder, then in Xcode you can either: (a) remove the fr.lproj directory and re-add it, or (b) select the red entry, open the right-hand (properties) panel, and near the top you should see the path. Change the path to the new location and it'll go back to black.

Comment: Changing the path doesn't work.  See the screenshot I added to the original post.  There's no option to change the path.  It's displayed, but there's no file icon like you'd have with a class or xib.

Comment: I also can't right click the file and Delete it from the pop up menu.  This option appears for normal files, but no for the Localizable.strings files.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to SoftDesigner's answer from 10 years ago, you can still do something like this in Xcode 14 by:

1. Move/drag the `Localizable.strings` file to wherever you want within your project, which also moves all the language localizations under it
2. Select your Project in the project navigator. In your Target's Build Phases tab, under the Copy Bundle Resources, click the `Localizable.strings` and click the minus (-) button
3. In that same tab, click the plus (+) to re-add the `Localizable.strings`
4. Select `Localizable.strings` in the project navigator, and on the right-hand info inspector, click the little folder icon under Location. Select your Localizable.strings file in the file select dialog

For me, this reset the location to where I put it, and the Builds could then find them successfully. (I'm not even 100% sure if steps 2 and 3 are always necessary.)