# Xcode Localization Building -

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I am trying to build the project. The project has localization.

When I build the project, it does not create Base.lproj in the .app.

So, it crashes for Base localization.

This has happened only after the checked-in the code, then checked out a new code.

Comment: When you create a new project, the Base.lproj is created at the same time. Have you deleted the folder occasionally ?

Comment: I had delete the folder occasionally. But, the older project which I checked in works fine, for which it copy's the file even if i reset the simulator.

Comment: Is there any way to specify Base localization folder path.I was hoping some help from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237285/moving-localization-folders-in-xcode-4

Comment: The new code that I check out , did not had "Target Membership" selected for those xib's and images. So, I have to set them by checking the box.